# Generar impresión de imagen en pdf o directamente

Tags: php, imagen

Hola estoy intentando imprimir una imagen que esta en un link dentro de una tabla. el link lo convierto a imagen dentro de la misma tabla

intente varias opciones de impresión y aun asi no me lo genera intente JS onclick y nada

```
<?php
/////// CONEXIÓN A LA BASE DE DATOS /////////
$host = 'localhost';
$basededatos = '11234';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = '';

$conexion = new mysqli($host, $usuario,$contraseña, $basededatos);
if ($conexion -> connect_errno)
{
    die("Fallo la conexion:(".$conexion -> mysqli_connect_errno().")".$conexion-> mysqli_connect_error());
}

//////////////// VALORES INICIALES ///////////////////////

$tabla="";

$query="SELECT * FROM dhlecommercecl ORDER BY id";

///////// LO QUE OCURRE AL TECLEAR SOBRE EL INPUT DE BUSQUEDA ////////////
if(isset($_POST['dhlecommercecl1']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['dhlecommercecl1']);
    $query="SELECT * FROM dhlecommercecl WHERE 

        id_order LIKE '%".$q."%' OR

        trackingNumber LIKE '%".$q."%' OR

        packageId LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$buscarOrden=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarOrden->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.= 
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
            <td>ID Order</td>
            <td>Numero Tracking</td>
            <td>Imagen</td>
            <td>Packete ID</td>

        </tr>';

    while($fila= $buscarOrden->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $tabla.=
        '<tr>
            <td>'.$fila['id_order'].'</td>
            <td>'.$fila['trackingNumber'].'</td>


           <td><img src="'.$fila['url'].'" height="250" whidth="75"/></td>


            <!--<td><img src='.$fila['url'].' height="250" whidth="75" /> <a target="_blank" /></td>-->

            <td>'.$fila['packageId'].'</td>



         </tr>
        ';
    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de búsqueda.";
    }


echo $tabla;
?>
```

Comment: Y qué contiene el html de la tabla, si miras el código fuente de la página en el browser? (PS: no entiendo qué podría tener que ver la generación de un PDF con lo que estás describiendo)

Comment: que estoy intentando sacar a imprimir la imagen que me trae desde la BD la cual intento que la saque en pdf o directo a la impresora
el html tiene solo la cabecera